# How to get content of each active tab in column of Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm writing a plugin for Sublime, able to get content of active view via `self.view`. But if I have two opened files in different columns, how to get content (or at least `window.id`) of active tab in each window via [SublimeText3 API](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html)? Shall it be done via `views()` method of `sublime.Window` class?

```
class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        print (self.view.id())
```

-> it works

```
class TestCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        print (self.window.views())
```

-> it doens't works and there is no errors in console when I ran `view.run_command('test')`

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation you linked, `self.window.views()` returns a list of views. Views are objects, and cannot be printed. Try this instead:

```
class TestCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        print([view.id() for view in self.window.views()])
```

This will print the unique id of each view in the window. You can substitute any method of [`sublime.View`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.View) if you want.

To run `WindowCommand`s from Sublime's console, use

```
window.run_command("command_name")
```

whereas a `TextCommand` is run by accessing the `view` object:

```
view.run_command("command_name")
```

Comment: Hi Matt, it doesn't work :( same no output when run `>>> view.run_command('test')`

Comment: I got it, need to run window instead of view `>>> window.run_command('test')` and remove self from run arguments